# for each element with this id jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i set value for each #path (not only for first)?

```
<input id="path"/>
<input id="path"/>
```

Code:

```
$('#path').each(function() {
    $('#path').val("123");
});
```

Comment: Id's need to be unique

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an XY problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can multiple different HTML elements have the same ID if they're different types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id should be unique, use a class instead.

```
<input class="path"/>
<input class="path"/>

$('.path').val("123");
```

And when you are setting a common value by using a class selector, there is no need to iterate.